# Compare two columns and get unique values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe in which some values are in two different columns

```
Ligand_hit,Ligand_miss
M00001,M00005
M00002,M00001
M00003,M00007
M00004,M00003
```

I would like to create a new column with all values in "Ligand_miss" that are not in "Ligand_hit". The desired output would be something like:

```
Ligand_hit,Ligand_miss,Unique
M00001,M00005,M00005
M00002,M00001,M00007
M00003,M00007,NaN
M00004,M00003,NaN
```

I tried to use "pandas.isin", but it only outputs boolean values. Is there a simple way to get the desired results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A direct pandas solution can be this one:

```
df["Unique"] = df["Ligand_miss"][~df["Ligand_miss"].isin(df["Ligand_hit"])].drop_duplicates()

  Ligand_hit Ligand_miss  Unique
0     M00001      M00005  M00005
1     M00002      M00001     NaN
2     M00003      M00007  M00007
3     M00004      M00003     NaN
```

this provides index-lookup for the unique values.

Answer (score 4):

A basic list comprehension will do:

```
[i for i in df.Ligand_miss if i not in df.Ligand_hit]
```

You can also use sets for this:

```
list(set(df.Ligand_miss)-set(df.Ligand_hit))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use vanilla python, thanks to `set`:

```
In [129]: df
Out[129]: 
  Ligand_hit Ligand_miss
0     M00001      M00005
1     M00002      M00001
2     M00003      M00007
3     M00004      M00003

In [130]: pd.concat([df, pd.Series(list(set(df['Ligand_miss'].values) - set(df['Ligand_hit'].values)))], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
Out[130]: 
        0       1       2
0  M00001  M00005  M00007
1  M00002  M00001  M00005
2  M00003  M00007     NaN
3  M00004  M00003     NaN
```

Some explanations:

- `set(df['Ligand_miss'].values)` and `set(df['Ligand_hit'].values)` get the unique values in the 2 columns.
- `set(...) - set(...)` computes the difference (the "Unique") per your requirements.
- [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) merges the result into the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in Pandas called [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). You can use that to find the values from *Ligand_miss* which are in *Ligand_hit*. The reverse of which is the values from *Ligand_miss* which are not in *Ligand_hit*. Then you have to subset your data frame based on the reverse and save it in a new column. For example:

Lets say you have the data frame *items_data* as below:

```
col_a  col_b
a_1    b_1
a_2    b_2
a_3    a_3
a_4    b_4
a_5    b_5
```

You can create a new column called *col_def* by this line of code:

```
items_data['col_def'] = items_data['col_a'][~items_data['col_a'].isin(items_data['col_b'])]
```

This will give you items from column *col_a* which are not in *col_b* by reversing the results of the isin() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Unique']=df.loc[~df['Ligand_miss'].isin(df['Ligand_hit']),'Ligand_miss'].reset_index(drop=True)

df
Out[624]: 
  Ligand_hit Ligand_miss  Unique
0     M00001      M00005  M00005
1     M00002      M00001  M00007
2     M00003      M00007     NaN
3     M00004      M00003     NaN
```